# Python regex (.*?) isn't giving an output

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I'm making a project and part of it is taking in a python file as a text file and parsing it using regular expressions.

I was able to use this fine (where program is a string containing the code with newlines):

```
findall(r"def (.*?)\((.*?)\)", program)
```

But this line just gives None when I expect it to give a Match object where .group() returns "func1(None, None)"

```
mainblock = search(r'if __name__ == "__main__":(.*?)#END', program)
```

An abbreviated version of the python file I'm parsing is below:

```
def func1(stuff, morestuff):
    pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    func1(None, None)
#END
```

I've checked for any discrepencies in the regex itself and I can't find any. I also tried copy/pasting it directly from the code file and it still couldn't find a match

Comment: Yes, program is just a long string with the program in and I also tried adding multiline - it still couldn't find it

Comment: It seems to work for me: https://ideone.com/rS2slo

Comment: `.*?` doesn't go across newlines unless you use the `re.MULTILINE` modifier.

Comment: @Barmar Just tried that, still returns None

Comment: Yeah, got confused there. The answer below got the right flag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to either include the newline characters `\n` in the regular expression, like this,

```
r'if __name__ == "__main__":\n(.*?)\n#END'
```

or enable the [`DOTALL`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.DOTALL) flag, meaning that `.` also matches line breaks.

([`MULTILINE`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.MULTILINE) means  something else, which can be counterintuitive.)

Comment: Here's a working demo of DOTALL. https://ideone.com/rS2slo

Comment: DOTALL worked perfectly

Comment: MULTILINE should have been named something like ANCHOR_TO_LINE....